# Why does @my_array = undef have an element?

Tags: perl, arrays

```
@my_array = undef;
if (@my_array ) {  
    print 'TRUE'; 
} else {
    print 'FALSE';
}
```

This will print `TRUE`

Why does the array have an element ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The array has an element because you assigned one. Consider the following:

```
@array = undef;  # Assigns the value 'undef' to @array
@array = ();     # Assigns the empty list to @array
undef @array;    # Undefines @array
```

They look similar, but the first line is different from the other two (which are equivalent). The first line results in array with a single element (the value `undef`). The other two result in an empty array. In Perl, `undef` is both a value and an operator. The first line uses it as a value, the last line uses it as an operator.

It isn't usually necessary to clear an array. They are empty when declared:

```
my @array;  # There's nothing in here, yet
```

Comment: Side remark: for scalar variables $p = undef and undef $p are equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

See [What is Truth?](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol4_2/tpj0402-0002.html) for more on boolean values in Perl. (If you're coming from another language, you may be in for a few other surprises, so it's worth a read.)

Here's a key bit from the article:

> `defined` and `undef` are good for
>   testing and setting scalars. Don't try
>   them with arrays, though. Presently,
>   `defined(@array)` returns true if Perl
>   has allocated storage for array
>   something that is weird and not useful
>   to the average programmer. To return
>   an array to its initial state, we say:
>
> ```
> @array = ();        # good
> ```
>
> To say `@array = undef` is to make `@array`
>   contain a one-element list, with the
>   single element being the scalar value
>   `undef`. This is hardly ever what we
>   want.

One other tip: localize your variables with `my`: my @array = ( #whatever );

Answer (score 8):

In Perl, `undef` is a valid value.  You can put one (or any number) of `undef`s into an array or list.

If you want to remove all elements of an array, do this:

```
@my_array = ();
```

Comment: Alternately, you can do "undef @my_array"

Comment: or $#my_array = -1;.   or splice(@my_array,0,@my_array);.

Comment: @Ysth: I'm curious: why not just splice @my_array?

From perldoc -f splice: "If both OFFSET and LENGTH are omitted, removes everything."